# Disable click event on Next button on checkout form's first step if all cart products are removed

Tags: forms, commerce, javascript

I am new to learning jQuery and JavaScript. I have small task that is becoming hard to solve.

On step one of a checkout form `#ps-cart-checkout-form`, I have to disable `<div class="button">Next</div>` when cart table is empty or emptied by clicking an "X" image in cart table row So that user does not go forward. Button's location and HTML is:

```
<div class="small-right">
<span class="page">Side <span class="current">1</span>/2</span>
<div class="button">Next</div>
</div>
```

Cart table `(.table-cart)` when having one or more products it contains `<thead>` tag but when empty the `<thead>` becomes `<tbody>` with one row `<th>` in it.

My approach:

I have tried to create a module that add js on hook_form_alter. and in js file. I have created :

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myModule = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
      var $form = $("#cart-checkout-form");
      if($($form.find("thead").lenght == 0) {
        $(".button").unbind( "click" );
        }

      });
   }
}(jQuery));
```

With above code I am trying to find out if there is no `<thead>` that means table is empty and therefore above code should disable the click next button. 
There already having a jQuery code that handles click event on Next div.

Answer (score 0):

What module are you using for the cart?

you can also use preventDefault() function to stop the page from loading to the next page.